# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128

Tags: azure-devops, pip, azure-pipelines, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to download internal Git on Google Colab for running ML models; however, at first, I download like this

```
!pip install git+https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx
```

It shown error so I found out in this website https://qdmana.com/2022/02/202202190011230865.html, showing that replace https with git like this may help.

```
!pip install git+git://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx
```

Nevertheless, it still shown the error as below,

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting git+git://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx
  Cloning git://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx to /tmp/pip-req-build-mmz02x7l
  Running command git clone -q git://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx /tmp/pip-req-build-mmz02x7l
  fatal: unable to connect to dev.azure.com:
  dev.azure.com[0: 13.107.42.20]: errno=Connection timed out
  dev.azure.com[1: 2620:1ec:21::20]: errno=Cannot assign requested address

WARNING: Discarding git+git://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx /tmp/pip-req-build-mmz02x7l Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx /tmp/pip-req-build-mmz02x7l Check the logs for full command output.
```

How do we address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use codes below instead:

```
git clone https://{your username}:{your password}@dev.azure.com/xxxxxxx
```